# XSLT arbitrary character

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm transforming XML document through XSL and I have more elements starting with the same letter, but ending with different numbers. In this example it is DTM_*:

---

```
`<DTM_01>
   <idDTM_01>DTM</idDTM_01>
   <DTM_01_C507>
.
.
.
 <DTM_14>
   <idDTM_14>DTM</idDTM_14>
   <DTM_14_C507>`
```

---

I need to work with all of them at once, not to make single template for each one of them like this:

---

```
`<xsl:template match="DTM_01">
 <E1EDK03>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </E1EDK03>
```

`

---

I just want to ask if there is any way, to set this template of the parent element, to be able to work with all the children of these "DTM" parents?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use the XPath function `starts-with(., 'DTM_')` in your predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "*to set this template of the parent element, to be able to work with all the children of these "DTM" parents?*" A template "works" with the node it matches. If you want your template to match elements named `DTM_01`, `DTM_02`, `DTM_14` and so on, make it:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'DTM_')]">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:template>
```